# How to print like jupyter notebook's default cell output

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I faced a problem while printing pandas dataframes in jupyter notebook. If the column names are really long it breaks the dataframe structure in different lines.

How can I print it like the way jupyter notebook does it by default(Shown in image - third cell)? As far as I know, only way to print the dataframe in bordered table style, you have to leave the variable name as the last command of the notebooks cell.

[image]

Here's the code if you want to check it,

```
d = pd.DataFrame({'A1_column':[1, 2, 4], 'B1_column':['a', 'b', 'd'],
                 'A2_column':[1, 2, 4], 'B2_column':['a', 'b', 'd'],
                 'A3_column':[1, 2, 4], 'B3_column':['a', 'b', 'd'],
                 'A4_column':[1, 2, 4], 'B4_column':['a', 'b', 'd'],
                 'A5_column':[1, 2, 4], 'B5_column':['a', 'b', 'd'],
                 'A6_column':[1, 2, 4], 'B6_column':['a', 'b', 'd'],
                 'A7_column':[1, 2, 4], 'B7_column':['a', 'b', 'd']})
print(d)
d
```

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You can use IPython's `display` function to achieve that:

```
from IPython.display import display
display(d)
```

[image: display screenshot]